# Create table with dbDelta,can't put any DEFAULT data

Tags: database, dbdelta

I want to add more custom tables to wp_users.
but I want them to contain a default JSON data.
This one works...when the DEFAULT is empty...

```
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'toto_user_db_setup');
function toto_user_db_setup() {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_data = "wp_users";

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $game_1 = "CREATE TABLE $user_data (
        data1 tinytext DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        data2 tinytext DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        data3 mediumtext DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        data4 mediumtext DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        data5 longtext DEFAULT '' NOT NULL      
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta($game_1);

}
```

But when i put inside DEFAULT any value... it does not work at all.

```
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'toto_user_db_setup');
function toto_user_db_setup() {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_data = "wp_users";

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $game_1 = "CREATE TABLE $user_data (
        data1 tinytext DEFAULT 'test1' NOT NULL,
        data2 tinytext DEFAULT 'test2' NOT NULL,
        data3 mediumtext DEFAULT 'hello' NOT NULL,
        data4 mediumtext DEFAULT '2132' NOT NULL,
        data5 longtext DEFAULT 'dada' NOT NULL      
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta($game_1);

}
```

I did try to make it work hours.....but nothing.... please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It appears as though you're altering the `users` table - this is a WordPress core table (if using the `wp_` prefix) and this is **probably not** a good idea - create a separate table with an `ID` foreign key to avoid potential problems.
2. Use `$wpdb->prefix` to get the prefix that's actually being used on a given WordPress installation (you can't depend upon it being `wp_`, it's configurable)
3. [`dbDelta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/) is very particular but it *should* accept a default value; assign the results of `dbDelta()` to a variable to see what's happening:

   ```
   $result = dbDelta($game_1);
   var_dump( $result );
   ```

Comment: For some reason.... after i done $result = dbDelta($game_1);
var_dump( $result );... i can't login anymore

Comment: how do I get all users id to another database table?

Comment: @Kefka RE: logging in - this is probably because your script is outputting information (with `var_dump()`) before it can send headers - just remove the `var_dump()` call (and work on a local development instance if at all possible); RE: user ID's - this is a topic for a separate question.